# App.config and MS access database connection string C#

Tags: c#, connection-string, app-config

I need to set different 'Data Source' in the connection string in app.config and I dont'n know how to do this through C# code.

Suggestions and links would really help me, Thanks !

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/access/

Comment: What do you mean with _different Data Source_? A Connection String represent one data source, but you could have many connection strings in your config file

Comment: @Steve I need to set the path to the MS DB, I need to be flexible, at application startup, I want to specify the path to the database and put it into the connection string, in app.config because the database is not centralized, it can be moved to another directory

Comment: What is your opinion about this @Steve ?

Comment: There are many ways to do it. One is explained in an answer below albeit that answer is not valid for Access which needs OleDb and thus uses the [OleDbConnectionStringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your time @Steve !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use SqlConnectionStringBuilder class

```
    var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ChronosDataContext"];
    var conn = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString){
       DataSource = "something"
    };
```

Comment: I want the connection string to be in the app.config, and to modify this through C# code, would SqlConnectionStringBuilder help me in this scenario ?

Comment: yes.. I've updated my answer to show just that..

Comment: @Marty Access uses OleDb

Comment: Good point @Steve. OleDbConnectionStringBuilder  should be used instead of SqlConnectionStringBuilder in such a case. Usage is almost the same though

Answer (score 1):

You can use this connection string for sql server.

```
<add name="DbName" connectionString="Data Source=192.168.0.2\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=InexDb29;Integrated Security=False;User Id=XYZ;Password=123456;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

For Ms Access

```
<add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\Test1.accdb"
    providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
```